# Golang regex get value inside parentheses

Tags: regex, go

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`((.*))`)
    s := `(tag)SomeText`

    res := r.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    fmt.Println(res[1])
}
```

How to Get Value inside parentheses?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1- While it is simple using regex (try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nun3TQwyBk)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var rgx = regexp.MustCompile(`\((.*?)\)`)

func main() {
    s := `(tag)SomeText`
    rs := rgx.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    fmt.Println(rs[1])
}
```

output:

```
tag
```

---

2- but sometimes using `strings.Index` is fast enough (try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ufHGIwxp6ki)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func match(s string) string {
    i := strings.Index(s, "(")
    if i >= 0 {
        j := strings.Index(s, ")")
        if j >= 0 {
            return s[i+1 : j]
        }
    }
    return ""
}

func main() {
    s := `Some(tag)Text`
    r := match(s)
    fmt.Println(r)

}
```

output:

```
tag
```

---

3- This simple benchmark shows using regex takes 931ms and using `strings.Index` takes 43ms for 1000000 iterations.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var rgx = regexp.MustCompile(`\((.*?)\)`)

const n = 1000000

func main() {
    var rs []string
    var r string
    s := `(tag)SomeText`
    t := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        rs = rgx.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
    fmt.Println(rs[1]) // [(tag) tag]

    t = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        r = match(s)
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
    fmt.Println(r)

}

func match(s string) string {
    i := strings.Index(s, "(")
    if i >= 0 {
        j := strings.Index(s, ")")
        if j >= 0 {
            return s[i+1 : j]
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Hey, thx. yes for my program the speed of execution is really matters :)

Comment: The match function has a typo in the return - it produces a slice bounds out of range error at runtime. It should be return s[i+1 : **j+i**]

  `func match(s string) string {  
    i := strings.Index(s, "(")  
    if i >= 0 {  
        j := strings.Index(s[i:], ")")  
        if j >= 0 {  
            return s[i+1 : j+i]  
        }  
    }  
    return ""  
}`

Answer (score 1):

I got My problem solved by this regex

```
r := regexp.MustCompile(`\((.*?)\)`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to answers, I made my version of the code.
link: https://play.golang.org/p/b82iPZGU1gw

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func match(start, end, s string) string {
    i := strings.Index(s, start)
    if i >= 0 {
        j := strings.Index(s[i:], end)
        if j >= 0 {
            return s[i+len(start) : i+j]
        }
    }
    return ""
}

func main() {
    errText := `facebook: Error validating access token: Session has expired on Tuesday, 28-Jul-20 22:00:00 PDT. The current time is Wednesday, 29-Jul-20 17:55:22 PDT. (code: 190; error_subcode: 463, error_user_title: , error_user_msg: )`
    start := "code: "
    end := ";"
    r := match(start, end, errText)
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```