# golang regex how do I get the value after "value = "qwetruioopppalsjdj|" "

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to get the value from a string but I'm having so many problems with regex.

So I made this on the regex builder but it doesn't seem to work. Then I watched a YouTube video which showed me the same thing .

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("(?<=captcha_img\" value=)\".*")
    return re.String()
```

Here is the sample string the real string is 300 its a base 64 img that I'm trying to extract from a website.

```
" name="captcha_img" value="qwetruioopppalsjdj|" "
```

If anybody could explain to me regex in a way I can understand because I'm pretty lost at the moment. The people I normal ask can't really explain it to me in a way that I get it.

I have tried a few YouTube videos and also a regex builder but I can't seem to understand it.

```
input " name="captcha_img" value="qwetruioopppalsjdj|" "
```

Expected output  `qwetruioopppalsjdj`

Comment: Consider use of a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): [`\bvalue\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"`](https://regex101.com/r/DfQeXq/1) ([demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##JU7JCsIwEL3nK0JOSQ8Fr0JPgjdB6LGtJG3TmprNLFVQv73GODDMG@YtM5tts2y4sZlDxYQGQChrXIAYwFRoUgH9keMzf1oECAArczCvsPpPW56iDwejrJAc07ZfmYy89UWVGuHmgrqCIJqkU9RDDsIEvrKxDw7uK0izJBmi@4MHF4Ux1lom/TIub0Qz1XH/o@bI8ij0WAcn9FzHXrEwXHGyIpmYvi7P6RSkxknU7DoCPtv2BQ))

Comment: could you explain what this is doing because im really struggling to understand your code works but i really would like to know what it all dose .  so i can make my own . sorry to be a pain . but im really lost i look at the docs in golang and dont really get it

Comment: It's explained on the right side in [the regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DfQeXq/1) or see [this answer how to capture what's inside double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171492/5527985). How golang capturing works, I found e.g. [in that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908955/golang-regex-get-value-inside-parentheses) or also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483652/how-to-get-capturing-group-functionality-in-go-regular-expressions). [Lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like in your sample are not supported in golang afaik.

Comment: so how would i do this string   name="captcha_img" value=" qwertyuiopasdfghjkl\zxcvbnm,"

Comment: Please edit your question with input/desired output examples, it's not clear (also the title *get value **after** value="..."*). Answers are as good as problem described mostly. :)

Comment: ok i edited it the listing again

Comment: If you want to match the `captcha_img` part before, just [add this to the regex](https://regex101.com/r/LbhrLw/1). `\s` matches any *whitespace* and `\b` a *word boundary*. Also see the [Stack Overflow Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5527985) for getting started.

Comment: i want to match the whole thing and start the cpature after the " and end at the " after the value=

Comment: Please show some examples of input and expected output.

Comment: ok i have updated to show input and excepted output

Comment: bobble bubble . when i add that it then give me the string value . because that is inbetween the two "" is there a way to get only the information after the " . i saw this but it doesnt work in golang (?<

Comment: @nitro_fox Place the capture group, where you want to capture something. A regex that's *capturing* exactly the same like your lookbehind matching example will be [`captcha_img\" value=\"(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/aIevn6/1)

Comment: Try the following, _(?<=captcha_img\" value=\")[^|]*_